# wish sentences... wish+would vs wish+could negative sentences

Tags: questions

Hello everyone I have a question about sentences with *wish*.
We all know that when both subjects are identical in sentences with *wish* for the future,   *would* changes to *could*, but something I am doubtful about is whether can we employ *couldn't* in these sentences.

For instance we say

> A: *I wish he would stay* --> negative form *I wish he wouldn't stay*
>   B: *I wish I could stay home, there is a football match on TV* --> negative form *I wish I ? I hate football...*

We can't use *couldn't* right?
How about in other sentences, can we use *couldn't* in other examples?
thanks so much

Comment: *I wish I didn't have to stay home*.

Comment: which means we can never use couldn't in statements with with wish for the future right? how about this sentence, I wish I was not going to stay home?

Comment: What "we all know" is not what you think, I'm afraid. This is not the way these things are decided. Modals work rather strangely in irrealis.

Comment: Things like *"I wish I couldn't read minds"* and *"I wish I couldn't cry"* seem fine to me. But I can't give you the rules for what's grammatical.

Comment: I wish I couldn't read minds means I can read minds so, I wish I couldn't read minds, so this is not about the future, so it is perfectly fine to me as well, as is I wish couldn't cry, which means I can cry and I wish I couldn't cry ( for a situation you can't stop crying) , but can we say I wish I couldn't cry tomorrow? is this also correct?

Comment: @ John Lawler, Very astute sir, There are occasions on which you feel, it is an arduous task, to figure out how things work in English, I know generalizing things the way I did, is really wrong. However, since English is a foreign language in my country, I maintain it is not that odd to encounter such problems. please don't leave me alone with my last question, this will help me puzzle out half of the puzzle at hand, can we say 'I wish I couldn't cry tomorrow?' is this correct?

Comment: So you wish that tomorrow you would not be capable of crying?

Comment: yes like, there is a sad occasion, and you hope you can overwhelm your emotions, so that you won't cry...

Comment: 'So you wish that tomorrow you would not be capable of crying?' so it is this ridiculous when you make such a statement right? So I got all I needed I presume, syntactically it is ok but semantically it does not make sense right?

Comment: I got it all, I can't thank you enough for helping me out here, I knew a bilingual who shed some light on the problem, just made a phone call and she told me how it was, and I know how stupid my questions were right from the beginning. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this an acceptable sentence to you?

> I wish I had an obligation that prevented me from staying home because I hate football.

If yes, then I believe it follows that the shortened form is also acceptable, even if the sentence is rare.

> I wish I couldn't stay home because I hate football.

From another perspective, I believe the following two sentences are analytically the same and both valid.

> I wish I were required to work on Christmas because my house is overrun by my family.
>
> I wish I couldn't be at my house on Christmas because my house is overrun by my family.

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't does not make sense in these situations. Can is 'to be able to' and couldn't is simply could not. [past tense]

- A: I wish he would stay --> negative form I wish he were not staying here
- B: I wish I could stay home, there is a football match on TV --> negative form I wish I was not at home right now ...

Comment: No, "I wish I could" is the same as "I wish I were able to".